# How to resolve 'Error 413 request entity too large' when building Amplify web app with large file?

Tags: aws-amplify

Amplify build with large file "Error 413 request entity too large".

Developers put pdf file (~10mb) in git repository with nextJS project. Then i build it by Amplify (web app without backend) and want to open pdf from link but i receive "Error 413 request entity too large". I tred find parameters like in nginx “client_max_body_size” but unfurtunately didn't. Can anyone explain how to solve that problem?